# Using multiple Webpack loaders to transform SVGs into React components

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to combine several Webpack loaders together to load my SVG assets, transform them for inline usage and finally to convert the result into an actual React component that can be used in the application.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['env', {
                browsers: supportedBrowsers,
                modules: false
              }]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
            options: {
              removeTags: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'svg-react-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If `svg-react-loader` is used on it's own the loader works as expected, however a lot of SVG assets have unneeded elements and attributes I would like to strip out using `svg-inline-loader`.

When the configuration is used as above the result will be loaded as text instead of executable JavaScript.

I am using the following loaders in my attempt to accomplish this:

- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader
- https://github.com/jhamlet/svg-react-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be ok to use other loaders? You can combine [svgo-loader](https://github.com/rpominov/svgo-loader) with `svg-inline-loader` and use all the possible options provided by [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo#what-it-can-do).

If so just do `npm i -D svgo-loader`

And change your webpack config to this:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    'svg-react-loader',
    {
      loader: 'svgo-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {cleanupAttrs: true}
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

Comment: This would be an acceptable solution to me, however I would still like to know what the reason is this setup is not working.

Comment: @JonKoops becasue `svg-inline-loader` loads svg as string so it can be used inline, in your html or javascript. `svg-react-loader` expects a svg file